# Analyzing data: PCD file. Problem: Bad PCD format

Tags: python

I get "Bad PCD format" error.

I would like to know what's wrong with the PCD file.

This is the header to the PCD file:

```
header = "# .PCD v.7 - Point Cloud Data file format
VERSION .7
FIELDS x y z data
SIZE 4 4 4
TYPE F F F
COUNT 1 1 1
WIDTH 0
HEIGHT 1
VIEWPOINT 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
POINTS 0
DATA binary"
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. The code you posted has a minor syntax error because of incorrect quotes in a multiline string, but there's no code that can say "Bad PCD format" here

Answer (score 0):

This should be work. Your `FIELDS` `SIZE` `TYPE` AND `COUNT` are not matchmaking.

```
header = """# .PCD v.7 - Point Cloud Data file format
VERSION .7
FIELDS x y z data
SIZE 4 4 4 4
TYPE F F F U
COUNT 1 1 1 1
WIDTH 0
HEIGHT 1
VIEWPOINT 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
POINTS 0
DATA binary
"""
```